# A Banach space $X$ is relfexive iff $X^*$ is reflexive.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am trying to prove the following:

A Banach space $X$ is reflexive iff $X^*$ is reflexive.

Thus far, I have proven the forward direction:

Let $J_X:X\mapsto X^{**}$ be the mapping defined by $J_X(x)=x^{**}$ and let $J_{X^*}:X^*\mapsto X^{***}$ be defined by $J_{X^*}(x^*)=x^{***}$. The statement above is equivalent to showing that $J_X(X)=X^{**}$ if and only if $J_{X^*}(X^*)=X^{***}$.
Suppose that $J_X(X)=X^{**}$. Let $y\in X^{***}=B(X^{**},\mathbb{R})$. We show that there is some $x^*\in X^*$ such that $J_{X^*}(x^*)=y$, thus showing that $J_{X^*}(X^*)=X^{***}$. Note that $yJ_X:X\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, and hence, $yJ_X\in B(X,\mathbb{R})=X^*$. Since $J_X(X)=X^{**}$, if $z\in X^{**}$, then there is some $x\in X$ such that $J_X(x)=z$. We have
$$ y(z)=y(J_X(x))=(J_X(x))(yJ_X)=z(yJ_X)=(J_{X^*}(yJ_X))(z). $$
Thus, $y=J_{X^*}(yJ_X)$, implying that $X^*$ is reflexive.

I have no clue how to prove the other direction. I wanted to try a similar approach, but it's turning out to be kind of difficult (and ugly looking). I would greatly appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: You can see http://image.sciencenet.cn/olddata/kexue.com.cn/upload/blog/file/2010/12/2010127131928961750.pdf. Page 70.

Comment: @ValdinêsJúnior Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.